# Best way to return different values depending on list emptyness

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Given a list, what is the best way to return a value depending on the empty-ness of that list?

Using match?

```
xs match {
    case Nil => a
    case _ => b
}
```

Or an if statement?

```
if (xs.isEmpty) a else b
```

It seems that pattern matching triggered a lot of a boilerplate in this case. Is there an idiomatic solution for this case?

Comment: Common anti-pattern I tired to see is `flag match { case true => ??? ; case false => ??? } ` :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Preference" is subjective, but the **simple `if`** has a few advantages:

- there doesn't seem to be a need to use pattern matching in this case, since you're not really exploiting its functionality (no extraction for example).
- the second approach tells you explicitly that you check whether the list is empty, and hence is immediately readable.

In summary: pattern matching in Scala is a powerful tool, and because of its power it adds complexity to your code, both in terms of machine- and human-readability. In other words: not everything is a nail ;).

Answer (score 1):

The pattern match syntax is preferred when you need recursion or `head :: tail`. `List` in Scala is inspired by older ML languages(`Cons(head, tail)`) and you get a nice `head :: tail` pair to match:

```
someList match {
   case head :: tail => // this will actually be someList.head and someList.tail
   case Nil => // ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say it's nicer, but an alternative is:

```
 xs.headOption.fold(a)(_ => b)
```

In this case, it looks a little bit weird because you're ignoring the head element and returning `b` instead, but if you actually wanted to use it as return value, the following is quite elegant:

```
xs.headOption.getOrElse(a)   //will return the head element or a if none
```

My favourite would be adding some `scalaz`:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._


xs.headOption ? b |  a    // if defined 'b' else 'a'
```